# Move track to another station

Tags: pandora

What does it mean to "Move track to another station"?  How does this feature work?

I like the idea of this option, but I'm not sure what it does.  I've tried moving tracks several times and cannot tell if anything changes on the initial station or the other station.  I also can't find a menu showing that anything happened for either station.  Does the track need a thumb up/down before you can move it?

[image: Move track]

**EDIT**

I am playing songs via the Shuffle feature on Firefox 28.0 for Windows 7, 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

It takes that song from the current playlist and adds it to a better suited playlist or station.

This helps curate the stations, removing  songs or tracks that don't fit with the rest and getting them into a station it does better fit.

Doing so will also [automatically thumbs up and down](https://help.pandora.com/customer/portal/articles/24586-how-do-i-move-a-track-to-a-different-station-) due to the move.

> When you do this the track will get a Thumbs down in the current station and a Thumbs up in the station you moved it to.

Comment: I just tried moving a track.  After checking the station it was on, there is no thumb-down for the track.  Checking the destination station (ha, rhyme) there is no thumb-up for the track.  I updated the question with some additional details.  Perhaps if you can confirm that this is how it works for you?

Comment: @DavidStarkey Check the seed tracks for the destination station. Unfortunately, the Pandora site is blocked here, so I can't verify it, but that's how I remember that working.

Comment: Station seed does not include the track.  It also does not include the artist.

Comment: They just changed the ui, and I don't see this anymore :(